# Conversão em C++: Qual a diferença entre static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast e reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, cast

Qual a diferença entre os *castings* presentes no C++?

Existem o `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `const_cast` e `reinterpret_cast`, qual a diferença entre estes? Quando usar cada um?

C++ também suporta o *cast* no estilo da linguagem C, como ele é interpretado pelo compilador?

Answer (score 16):

**A importância de compreender a conversão de tipos**

O C++ é uma linguagem dita *strictly typed*, termo geralmente traduzido como *fortemente tipada*, isto significa que o tipo das variáveis é sempre certo e as operações devem ser definidas para tipos específicos. Gerar um objeto de um tipo através de uma expressão de outro tipo envolve uma conversão, ou *casting*.

Vou explicar cada um dos tipos e adicionar exemplos ao fim da resposta:

---

> Existem o `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `const_cast` e `reinterpret_cast`, qual a diferença entre estes?

```cpp
static_cast<novo_tipo>(expressão);
```

- **static_cast**, *conversão estática*

  Esta é a conversão mais comum. É dita estática pois sua validade é analisada durante a compilação, as principais possibilidades são:

  - Conversão implícita entre os tipos (como `float` pra `int`).
  - Chamar um construtor do `novo_tipo` através do resultado da `expressão`.
  - Usar operador de conversão definido pelo usuário do resultado da `expressão` para o `novo_tipo`.
  - Converter ponteiros entre hierarquia de classes, desde que as classes não sejam virtuais. (`static_cast` não verifica a validade da conversão durante a execução.)
  - Converter ponteiros `void*` para qualquer outro tipo de ponteiro. (resultado indefinido se o alinhamento do ponteiro não for correto.)

```cpp
dynamic_cast<novo_tipo>(expressão);
```

- **dynamic_cast**, *conversão dinâmica*

  Esta conversão é especial para referências ou ponteiros de objetos polimórficos (classes contendo funções virtuais). É dita dinâmica pois verifica durante a execução do programa se a conversão é válida quando descendo na hierarquia das classes. Em principal:

  - Ao converter ponteiros *pra cima* na hierarquia (`expressão` é derivada de `novo_tipo`), comporta-se como uma conversão implícita.
  - Ao converter ponteiros *pra baixo* na hierarquia, (`expressão` é base de `novo_tipo`), verifica se `expressão` originalmente referia-se a um ponteiro para `novo_tipo` e, se sim, retorna o ponteiro ajustado. Caso a verificação falhe, retorna `nullptr`.
  - Conversão entre referências é semelhante, mas gera exceção `std::bad_cast` em caso de falha.

```cpp
const_cast<novo_tipo>(expressão);
```

- **const_cast**, *conversão de constância*

  Esta conversão tem a única função de adicionar ou remover a propriedade `const`. Qualquer conversão pode gerar uma referência ou ponteiro para um objeto para que este seja tratado como constante, mas apenas `const_cast` pode gerar uma nova referência ou ponteiro de um objeto constante para que este seja tratado como modificável (*não-constante*). Esta conversão não gera nenhuma instrução, é apenas uma diretiva para o compilador.

```cpp
reinterpret_cast<novo_tipo>(expressão);
```

- **reinterpret_cast**, *conversão por reinterpretação*

  Esta conversão é que mais se distancia da característica *fortemente tipada* da linguagem C++, pois comanda o compilador a reinterpretar o resultado da `expressão` como se fosse do `novo_tipo`, em geral sem realizar nenhuma operação nem verificação sobre os valores sendo convertidos. A grosso modo, `reinterpret_cast` é forma de dizer ao compilador: *"Confie em mim, esses números que estou lhe passando são o que digo ser"* . Seus principais usos são:

  - Converter ponteiro ou referência para qualquer tipo de objeto para ponteiro ou referência para qualquer outro tipo de objeto.
  - Converter um ponteiro para um número inteiro.
  - Converter um número inteiro para ponteiro.

---

> Quando usar cada um?

Procure usar a conversão que melhor expressa suas intenções. Como apenas a definição de cada tipo de conversão pode não ser muito elucidativa, seguem exemplos de cada uma:

- **static_cast**

A `static_cast` é a mais comum e geralmente ocorre implicitamente em uma conversão implícita, como no exemplo:

```cpp
int   i = 5;
float x = i; //conversão implícita 
float y = static_cast<float>(i); //conversão explícita
```

As conversões implícitas facilitam lidar com variáveis numéricas e locais, mas é recomendado sempre explicitar a conversão quando exportando a variável para alguma função. No exemplo abaixo, o resultado com e sem o `cast` é o mesmo (logo depois apontarei um possível problema):

```cpp
int f(int x)
{
  return x*2;
}

int main()
{
  float x = 1.f;
  std::cout << "Sem cast : " << f(x)                   << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Com cast : " << f(static_cast<int>(x)) << std::endl;
}
```

Resultado:

```
Sem cast : 2
Com cast : 2
```

Agora, digamos que seja introduzida uma nova função, sem alterar as partes existentes do código anterior:

```cpp
int f(double x)
{
  return x*5;
}
```

O resultado do programa altera-se:

```
Sem cast : 5
Com cast : 2
```

O motivo disso é que a conversão implícita de `float` para `double` é preferida ao invés da conversão implícita de `float` para `int`.

Embora requerida em alguns casos (como convertendo ponteiros `void*` para outros tipos) `static_cast` tem uma função que pende mais para boa organização e manutenção do código.

- **dynamic_cast**

`dynamic_cast` é a forma de verificar em tempo de execução se o tipo de objeto polimórfico passado é de um determinado tipo (para isso o programa faz uso de RTTI, omitirei detalhes). Em um exemplo simplificado, imagine uma classe base com dois tipos de derivadas:

```cpp
struct Base{
    virtual ~Base(){};
};

struct DerivadaA : public Base
{};

struct DerivadaB : public Base
{};
```

Digamos então que temos uma função que deve lidar com objetos do tipo `Base`,

```cpp
void f(Base* ponteiro_base)
```

Mas em algum momento a execução deve ser diferente se o objeto passado for `DerivadaA` ou `DerivadaB`. Como `dynamic_cast` retorna `nullptr` em caso de falha, podemos fazer o seguinte:

```cpp
void f(Base* ponteiro_base)
{
    //tenta cast para ponteiro do tipo DerivadaA
    DerivadaA * objA = dynamic_cast<DerivadaA*>(ponteiro_base);
    if(objA != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout<<"Objeto do tipo A" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    
    //tenta cast para ponteiro do tipo DerivadaB
    DerivadaB * objB = dynamic_cast<DerivadaB*>(ponteiro_base);
    if(objB != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout<<"Objeto do tipo B" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

[Clique aqui para ver o exemplo acima em ação](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03ad0d5c840a0409).

- **const_cast**

Remover a propriedade `const` de um objeto é necessidade rara, e modificar um objeto declarado `const` resulta em comportamento indefinido do programa, então cabe ao programador usar de forma coesa essa conversão.

Um exemplo ilustrativo: Quando deseja-se retornar uma referência a um membro de uma classe (os famosos `setters` e `getters`):

```cpp
class ClasseX
{
    int X;
public:
    //retorna referência a membro da classe
    int& getRefX()
    {
        return X;
    };
};
```

Como a função não altera o estado da classe, posso querer marcá-la `const`:

```cpp
int& getRefX() const
```

Mas daí o código não compila (a assinatura `const` da função torna seus membros `const` dentro desta)...

```
error: binding 'const int' to reference of type 'int&' discards qualifiers
```

`const_cast` pode ser usado para retornar a referência não-constante:

```cpp
    //retorna referência a membro da classe
    int& getRefX() const
    {
        //(algum comentário explicando o const_cast)
        return const_cast<int&>(X);
    };
```

`const_cast` deve ser usado com muito cuidado, pois alterar o valor de uma variável originalmente constante torna o programa mal formado (undefined behaviour). No exemplo acima, se algum objeto da classe `ClasseX` fosse originalmente constante, a função ainda funcionaria neste, mas o valor de `X` não deveria ser modificado através da referência retornada.

- **reinterpret_cast**

O `reinterpret_cast` afasta-se da noção de objetos e aproxima-se da noção de bits (informação).

Por exemplo, digamos que você esteja programando um microcontrolador e no manual deste diz que a placa de som lê as informações a partir do endereço `33` na memória:

```cpp
//endereço obtido do manual do microchip
static const int ADDR_PLACA_DE_SOM = 33;
```

Para escrever informações nesta área da memória, você precisa converter esta posição para um ponteiro, com `reinterpret_cast` você pode fazê-lo:

```cpp
//cria ponteiro para inteiros na posição dita pelo manual
int* som_pt = reinterpret_cast<int*>(ADDR_PLACA_DE_SOM);
```

Note que a conversão é bem livre, você pode criar um ponteiro para qualquer tipo de dado:

```cpp
//cria ponteiro para chars na posição dita pelo manual
char* som_pt = reinterpret_cast<char*>(ADDR_PLACA_DE_SOM);
```

---

> C++ também suporta o *cast* no estilo da linguagem C, como ele é interpretado pelo compilador?

As *conversões no estilo-C* são do tipo:

```cpp
(novo_tipo)(expressão)
```

Um exemplo:

```cpp
//gera um inteiro através do float 3.14
(int)(3.14f)
```

Este tipo de conversão está presente no C++ principalmente por questões de compatibilidade com a linguagem C.

O compilador tenta a seguinte ordem de conversões quando um *cast no estilo-C* é utilizado:

1. `const_cast`.
2. `static_cast`, ignorando acesso restrito caso usado em hierarquias de classes.
3. `static_cast` seguido de `const_cast`
4. `reinterpret_cast`
5. `reinterpret_cast` seguido de `const_cast`

Ou seja, o compilador tenta **quase tudo** para gerar um objeto do novo tipo, inclusive removendo `const`. Esse tipo de conversão pode gerar conversões indesejadas (até o *não orientado a objetos* `reinterpret_cast`!) que escondem bugs propagáveis pela lógica do programa.

---

As principais referências foram:

cppreference (em inglês): [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast), [dynamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast), [const_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast), [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), [Explicit type conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)